# Wordpress Attachments from Media Library

Tags: wordpress, tags, attachment, categories, taxonomy

My wordpress attachment images have categories and tags. I'd like to call this information inside of a photo gallery.

Good news: the correct images appear when called in the loop. Bad news: I'm having trouble calling the specific data inside of the gallery. The problems are in all caps below:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'category_name' => 'architecture'
    ));
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
?>
<figure class="gallery-photo" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" data-groups='["all", "PHP ATTACHMENT TAG"]'>
    <a class="photo-link" href="<?php wp_get_attachment_image (); ?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="CALL PHP ATTACHMENT IMAGE WIDTH & HEIGHT">
        <img src="<?php wp_get_attachment_url ('full'); ?>" itemprop="thumbnail" />
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">PHP ATTACHMENT CAPTION</figcaption>
        <div class="photo-title"><h2>PHP ATTACHMENT IMAGE TITLE</h2></div>
    </a>
</figure>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Some things I tried, but didn't work:

1. `<?php $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($image->ID, true); echo '.$meta[width]."x".$meta[height].';?>`
2. `<?php $description = $post->post_content; echo $description;?>`
3. `<?php $image->post_title; ?>`

Here is the plugin, for reference:

```
// Custom media taxonomies
function add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );

function add_tags_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

These custom taxonomies are a new concept to me, so I'm trying to learn my way around them. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try getting the post meta that is attached to post ID (image with that ID)?

Comment: I think that's what I tried in #1, right?

Comment: I meant as `get_post_meta()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The below code is working. I defined `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js();` and `get_the_category()`, then used them for the functions inside of `echo`.

Essentially, I have a query that lists all media library attachments that fall under the category "photography." Then, it retrieves information about each attachment (title, caption, width, height, url, category name) inside of the gallery html container.

```
    <?php 
   $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'category_name' => 'photography'
    )); 

   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   $the_query->the_post();
  ?>
    <?php
 $attachment_data = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment->ID );
 $category = get_the_category($attachment->ID);
      echo '<figure class="gallery-photo" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" data-groups='. esc_attr('["all","'.$category[0]->cat_name.'"]').'>';
      echo'<a class="photo-link" href="'.$attachment_data['url'].'" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="'.$attachment_data['width'].'x'.$attachment_data['height'].'">';
      echo'<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url ('medium').'" itemprop="thumbnail"/>';
      echo'<div class="photo-title"><h2>'.$attachment_data['title'].'</h2></div></a>';
      echo'<figcaption itemprop="caption description">'.$attachment_data['caption'].'</figcaption></figure>';?>
   <?php 
   endwhile; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```